# Python: Convert 2D list to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert the following 2D list:

```
lst = [['A','B'],['C','D']]
```

To a dictionary like:

```
dict = {['A','B']:0, ['C','D']:1}
```

I have tried answers from other posts like the following:

```
{k: v for v, k in enumerate(lst)}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Lists and other mutable types cannot be dictionary keys. What do you want to do with this?

Comment: @tzaman compare it with another dictionary similar to this to find indexes of elements in the two.

Comment: but you can use tuple : `{ tuple(k): v for v, k in enumerate(lst)}`

Comment: [shameless plug for a hashable list implementation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashable_collections/1.1). But note the other answers are probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are mutable, and thus cannot be used as dictionary keys. You could convert them to tuples if you want:

```
{tuple(k): v for v, k in enumerate(lst)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutable types cannot be keys of a dictionary, but you can store tuples as dictionary keys for your purpose like this:

```
{tuple(k): v for v, k in enumerate(lst)}
```